# How to create a car from scratch in ROS

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I want to create a specific car in ROS - Ford Mondeo and i can't find a something like tutorial or examples of creating cars from scratch (these cars should look well, I mean look like a car, not like rectangle with wheels) and simulate them in rviz. Do you have some ideas which programs or packages I should use.
Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259715/how-to-create-a-car-from-scratch-in-ros/) by [aleksandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/30077/aleksandra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2017-04-20**:
Are you sure rviz is the best tool for your job? It seems to be designed as a diagnostic and monitoring tool, not for photorealism. Might you be better off with a gaming engine like Unity, or some 3-D rendering tool? Why does it have to "look like a car"?

**Comment by [aleksandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/30077/aleksandra/) on 2017-04-24**:
We are working in ROS and we want to present our vehicle to our partners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to make a car robot in ROS that looks pretty like a real car, you need a CAD model of a car that looks like a real car, preferably one with the wheels as separate models. You will then need to convert that model into a format that Gazebo and rViz can understand, such as the STL format or COLLADA .dae files. You can then use that to create a URDF or SRDF by using the CAD models as the visual representation of the links for the robot model. See the [URDF tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/) for how to build a URDF file and make it usable in simulation and visualisation. In those tutorials, replace the cylinders and boxes with [`<mesh>` tags](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/link#Attributes) that point to your CAD files.

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aleksandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/30077/aleksandra/) on 2017-04-24**:
Thanks a lot!!!